# SQL Recursion using stored procedures

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have two stored procedures.  The first stored procedure returns top level parents, the second procedure will return the children of a supplied parent ID.  Each child may also be a parent.

The problem I'm running into when researching CTE is that every example seems to rely on an ID+1, which won't work here since the item's ids are not sequential.  Any guidance here would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I'm not certain where to start.  I know that the problem requires recursion, but all the examples on CTE I can find require some form of sequential id, something that can increment or decrement to get to the next piece of data, which won't work here.

Comment: start by actually stating your problem, showing us your query, and your error

Comment: Can you provide some examples of IDs? How is the relationship maintained in the database? Do tables have parent and child columns?

Comment: You're not reading the examples right - the recursion is probably joining on _level_ + 1, not _ID_ + 1.

Comment: as long as the table has an ID and a ParentID a CTE will work.  However I assume parentID is NULL when an ID has no parents.  Otherwise you may have infinite recursion if a loop exists...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick CTE example that shows how to determine a depth in the query. The full SQL Fiddle is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c3f47/1/0

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Records.Id,
        Records.Name,
        Records.ParentId,
        CONVERT(INT, 1) AS Depth
    FROM dbo.Records Records
    WHERE Records.ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Records.Id,
        Records.Name,
        Records.ParentId,
        CTE.Depth + 1
    FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN dbo.Records Records
            ON CTE.Id = Records.ParentId
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Which for the example yields the following output:

```
| ID |  NAME | PARENTID | DEPTH |
|----|-------|----------|-------|
|  1 |     A |   (null) |     1 |
|  2 |     B |   (null) |     1 |
|  5 |   B.1 |        2 |     2 |
|  3 |   A.1 |        1 |     2 |
|  4 |   A.2 |        1 |     2 |
|  6 | A.1.1 |        3 |     3 |
|  7 | A.1.2 |        3 |     3 |
```